# mysql IN and other options

Tags: mysql

Hi I need to help in my query.
I want to find N rows with product

My query is:

```
 Select ...... WHERE
    s.id_prod = 2 AND s.sn IN(100,20) 
    LIMIT 3
```

BUT NOW I HAVE 3 product but one of them  haven't sn. 
How result 3 rows?

```
 s.sn IN(100,20 ,*)
```

What replace  '*' that it will work? 
IF I have 100 products and only 2 have se (uniqe) I have to have result 3 rows (with sn 100 and 20 and other any 3th row

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE s.id_prod = 2
ORDER BY s.sn IN(100,20) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

The idea is, that `s.sn IN(100,20)` evaluates to 1 or 0 depending on whether the property holds or doesn't hold. Ordering in a descending order on that property will list the records at the top, for wich the property holds.